# Disable motion blur in camera cuts (EEVEE)

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am relatively new to blender and I wanted to know if there is any way to deactivate the motion blur during a camera cut, it is when the camera moves from one place to another in an instant an image is generated between the sub frames or an "Effect ghost ". I need to know if there is any way to disable this or limit the sub frames in certain parts of the video. Thanks for your answers :D

Answer (score 1):

If the motion blur checkmark is animatable (which I don’t remember), you can. Otherwise, use multiple cameras, and use Ctrl+B on the timeline to place a marker for whatever selected camera to become the active camera at that time.